# Cardinality of the set of all grammatical english sentences.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let me preface this by saying that I am not a mathematician, nor am I even a mathematics student.

The question I am looking to answer is this one: "Is the set of all grammatical English sentences countable?"

I saw [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188078/how-do-we-determine-if-the-set-of-rational-numbers-and-the-set-of-all-english-se) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660793/prove-that-the-set-of-all-grammatical-sentences-is-denumerable) in favor of the answer that it is, and spoke to one of my professors who also answered in the affirmative. It would seem that the affirmative argument relies on the assumption that a sentence must be of finite length. I would certainly agree that [utterances](https://sites.google.com/site/linguisticsinaction/linguistics/subtopics/pragmatics) have a finite length, but do not see any definitions [(1)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sentence) [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_%28linguistics%29) of a sentence which constrain it to finite length.

For example, consider that for any two x,y $\in$ Grammatical Sentences, that x + "and" + y $\in$ Grammatical Sentences.

To be clear on the notation (because I'm sure I'm butchering it), let x be "Phil is a fisher" and y be "Cassey is my dog". "Phil is a fisher and Cassey is my dog" is grammatically correct because it is two grammatically correct phrases combined by a conjunction.

I can therefore construct an infinite sentence as such:

Let x be the square root of 2.

Sentence = ""

for digit d in x:

$\hspace{10mm}$ sentence = sentence + "and" + str(d) + "is a digit of this number"

end

The can be done for every x in $R$.

Therefore, the set of Grammatical Sentences must have at least as many elements as $R$, and cannot be countable.

However, the consensus seems to be that sentences are countable. Can anyone point me to where my misunderstanding lies?

Comment: Everyone else is assuming that grammatical sentences are finite.  Indeed, if you allow infinite sentences, the set becomes uncountable.

Comment: Here's an argument against infinite sentences: all infinite sentences end in a period.  However, infinite sentences fail to end.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: (tongue in cheek) The ordinal $\omega+1$ is a perfectly good ordinal, so nothing is stopping us from putting a period at the end of an infinite sentence.

Comment: English, or Entish? ;)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks very much for the reply, that all makes a lot of sense. I suppose we can't have an infinite sentence with a period for the same reason 0.9999 repeating = 1?

Comment: @MPW: Sorry, I'm not tracking on your reply, if that was intended for me.

Comment: This argument seems to be more about which meaning you assign to the word "sentence", than anything mathematical. (You probably need a better definition, however. As it stands, your example doesn't work: the "for digit $d$ in $x$" loop never terminates, so the algorithm doesn't produce _any_ sentence as output, finite or infinite).

Comment: @Henning Makholm: Thanks for your reply. As I understand a sentence, we don't need to write it down or have it in a computers memory for it to be valid. The for loop isn't meant to actually be run on a computer. Unfortunately, I am not a mathematician, so it was the best way I could think to express my idea. I'm sure we could get into another form that did not imply that it was supposed to be run by a machine in finite time.

Comment: @JohnMadden I wouldn't say that it's quite the same reason; the $0.999$ thing is more of a facet of the real numbers.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: OK, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, if sentences can be infinite, you can still stipulate that they end in a period — their length will just have to be a successor ordinal: the length of "$x\ne 0$ or $x\ne 1$ or ... ." is $\omega + 1$.  ;/

Comment: @JohnMadden None of your examples is actually infinitely long. You've shown that there are infinitely many grammatical English sentences, because there's no bound on their lengths; but given that the alphabet is finite, the whole set is countable.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for your reply. I dont see why the alphabet being finite implies sentences are countable; just because we can only choose between 10 digits does not make the set of all infinitely long decimals countable.

Comment: @JohnMadden: It was a Tolkien reference, quoting Treebeard: "You must understand, young Hobbit, it takes a long time to say anything in Old Entish. And we never say anything unless it is worth taking a long time to say." Purely for amusement.

Comment: @BrianO  i also fail to see how a sentence as long as an infinitely long number is not infinitely long. There are, as discussed above, issues eith the concept of an infinitely long sentence which is grammatically correct, but without the need for a period at the end, this example should meet the other criteria. I believe replacing "sentence" with "phrase" would be correct.

Comment: @JohnMadden Well, I've never read one or seen one. I've seen finite notations for and definitions of infinite objects, sure; some end in ellipses, others don't. I have nothing against against infinite sentences or phrases per se :) and I'm not a finitist. I just think that the consensus definition of "phrase (or sentence) of <any natural language>" entails finiteness. Notice, though, that generalized (possibly infinite) sentences can be infinite in the middle, and don't have to be infinite only "to the right": consider "I hate anti-anti-... ...-missile-missile-missiles."

Answer (score 0):

so, there is a 'countably infinite' and also 'uncountably infinite' property. what makes it 'countable' is not that you necessarily stop at some point, that would make it countably finite. 'Countable' is simply the property that you know what comes next (you can enumerate them). So if you start with the first word in the dictionary, then the second, etc until you do all single word sentences then next you can have 'firsWord firstWord' then 'firstWord secondWord' and so on. You'll never finish but you can count the sentences. Just like you can count all numbers, but there is no finite amount of numbers.